# python data type after bitwise operation (from c language)

Tags: python, c, hash, binary, bit-manipulation

i have been trying to convert one of the method from hashing quark, that originaly from c language, and im trying to change it to python, this method is used for showing the current state of hash, and i found a problem that my output, the pytho one, only give the output with binary, and the output that i was expecting is everything except binary, and how do i convert it? or are there is any other way to manipulate it?

code from python

```
def showstate(x):
    i = 0
    buf = 0
    width = 17
    #print (x)

    while i < 8 * width:
        buf ^= (1 & x[i] << (7 - (i%8)))

        #my_hex = buf.decode('hex')

        #print ("%d"%buf, end = '')
        if  (((i%8) == 7) and (i)):
            #print (" ".join(hex(ord(n)) for n in buf))
            #a = int(str(buf), 2)
            #print(a)
            print("%02x"%buf, end = '')
            buf = 0
        i += 1

    #print(x)
     #print ("/n")
```

output from python

```
ENTER PERMUTE
0000000001000101000100010001010100
PERMUTE DONE
0000000001000101010100000100010101
EXTRACTED ONE BYTE

ENTER PERMUTE
0000000001000101010100000100010101
PERMUTE DONE
0000000001000101010100000101000100
EXTRACTED ONE BYTE
```

code from c

```
void showstate( u32 * x ) {

  int i;
  u8 buf=0;
  for(i=0;i<8*WIDTH;++i) {
    buf ^= (1&x[i])<<(7-(i%8));
      /*printf("%d",buf);*/
    if (((i%8)==7) && (i)) {
      printf("%02x",buf); /*panjang nya 2 digit, kalau cuma satu digit diisi 0 */
      buf=0;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("%d", buf);
  printf("\n");

}
```

output from c is the correct one where the output has fix length of value, and random number

thanks guys

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? Because that output does not match your python code at all.

Comment: @FHTMitchell i want the output not binary, string that contain hexadecimal would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in the conversion from C to Python - the C line

```
    buf ^= (1&x[i])<<(7-(i%8));
```

has been translated to the Python line

```
    buf ^= (1 & x[i] << (7 - (i%8)))
```

whereby a parenthesis has been misplaced. The C line should rather have been copied as it was, just removing the `;`.